# Why is it not possible for one user to inject a Trojan horse into a package that might be used by another user?

Tags: package-management, nix

https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/introduction.html says

> **Multi-user support**
>
> Nix has multi-user support. This means that non-privileged users can
> securely install software. Each user can have a different profile, a
> set of packages in the Nix store that appear in the user’s PATH. If a
> user installs a package that another user has already installed
> previously, the package won’t be built or downloaded a second time. At
> the same time, **it is not possible for one user to inject a Trojan
> horse into a package that might be used by another user.**

Why is it not possible for one user to inject a Trojan horse into a package that might be used by another user?

Is the sentence before it says that some package may be a dependency shared by two applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in [the section on multi-user mode](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/installation/multi-user):

> To allow a Nix store to be shared safely among multiple users, it is important that users are not able to run builders that modify the Nix store or database in arbitrary ways, or that interfere with builds started by other users. If they could do so, they could install a Trojan horse in some package and compromise the accounts of other users.
>
> […] When a unprivileged user runs a Nix command, actions that operate on the Nix store (such as builds) are forwarded to a *Nix daemon* running under the owner of the Nix store/database that performs the operation.

In multi-user mode, package installations can be shared, but (untrusted) users can’t modify the shared packages.

> If a user installs a package that another user has already installed previously, the package won’t be built or downloaded a second time.

isn’t referring to dependencies; it means that (in multi-user mode) packages are shared by all users.